# Displaying a textarea between two labels with full width

Tags: html, css

I need to display a text area between two labels and the textarea need to use the maximum
width available without making any of the labels to move out of the row.

I've been trying with some styles without much luck!

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <span class="preTextContainer">Pre Text</span>
        <span><textarea class="fullWidthTextArea">Some text area content</textarea></span>
        <span class="postTextContainer">Post Text</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.preTextContainer {
    float:left;
}

.postTextContainer {
    float:right;
}

textarea.fullWidthTextArea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pGrpZ/

What I'm trying to achieve would look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems possible with something like the following.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="label">Pre Text</span>
    <span class="field "><textarea class="large">Some text area content</textarea></span>
    <span class="label">Post Text</span> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}

.field
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.label
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

textarea.large {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aP57W/

Answer (score 0):

100% means ALL so there is no space for your other text. Add to each span, let's say, 15%, and 70% for your textarea, all together ads up to 100%. You will need to make your spans display block. The border also counts!!! So you try just 69% or 68% for the textarea

```
.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.preTextContainer {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:15%
}

.postTextContainer {
    float:right;
    display:block;
    width:15%
}

textarea.fullWidthTextArea {
    width: 68%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JCpZu/

Comment: Unfortunately the labels are dynamic, hence the question :)

Comment: So show the demo with dynamic labels and how you want the view to react to it.

Comment: Then, you might need to use JS to get the width of each label and substract it from the 100% of the textarea. Although even of it is dynamic a percentage will always be respected, the text inside will need to adjust to that width.